USB pd Max76958 and restarting negotiations with tablet
USB pd Max76958 and restarting negotiation without disconnecting
Hi there, I am in a bit of a pickle and I was hoping someone could help.  I am using a maxim max77958 pd control to negotiation power control between a custom board and a tablet.  The tablet has control over data all the time as it is connected to a downstream hub.  However we want to change the tablet when vbus power becomes available.  I can get this to work by doing a power role swap when power is available and tablet is one.  However when tablet is off due to flat battery I cannot seem to be able to charge at higher than 500mA.  Note that our pd controller is configured as drp.  The tablet cannot be disconnected from our board.
Any ideas on how to handle tablet off case?
I have tried doing a soft reset.  It didn't work.
Also tried to configure as source but that also didn't work

This doesn't really seem like a programming question to me, more a question about USB PD and operating this particular chip. However, I'm not surprised that it would, at least initially, only charge at the default USB rate in the dead battery condition (depending on what chip is used in the tablet and how it's configured). The first thing I'd check is see at what rate a high-quality off-the-shelf PD charger will charge that tablet in the dead battery condition.

Thanks for responding.  It is not quite a programming question even tho the AP is being done in C and we are using a pic32mm with harmony 3.  Not the best choice.  I know. An off the shelf charges at 5v 3A.

Even if you're programming as part of of developing this system, you don't have a specific programming question, more of an open-ended application issue (which is difficult to answer unless someone has particular experience with this IC, and/or much more information about your implementation). This may be better-addressed for the support/forums on the Analog Devices site.

Thanks mate.  I sent them an email as well.  Cheers
